# alternative publisher for Joy_node

Tags: ros, joy-node, joy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I'm trying to publish to modify the [Publisher tutorial (Python)](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber(python)) and simplify [this tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/joy/Tutorials/WritingTeleopNode) in order to read some values from the joy_node, do some operations and publish the new values in another topic in the foo array.
This is my file talker2.py in Python under ROS Indigo.
I know there are errors (probably in the foo variable), but I don't know what is really wrong. Someone can help me?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import rospy
from std_msgs.msg import Float32MultiArray
from sensor_msgs.msg import Joy

def joyread(data):
    foo[0] = 4*data.axes[1]
    foo[1] = 4*data.axes[0]
    foo[2] = 15*data.buttons[14]
    pub.publish(foo)
  
def talker2():
    global pub
    pub = rospy.Publisher('chatter', Float32MultiArray,queue_size=10)
    rospy.Subscriber("joy", Joy, joyread)
    rospy.init_node('talker2', anonymous=True)
    rate = rospy.Rate(10) # 10hz
    while not rospy.is_shutdown():
      rospy.sleep(1.0)
      
      

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        talker2()
    except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
        pass
```

And this is the error (declaring public foo does not solve anything)

```
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1479037245.575886] bad callback: <function joyread at 0x7f5b6f923c08>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/topics.py", line 720, in _invoke_callback
    cb(msg)
  File "/home/marcor/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/scripts/talker2.py", line 44, in joyread
    foo[0] = 4*data.axes[1]
NameError: global name 'foo' is not defined
```

Thank you all.
(PS Joy_node "alone" works fine)

**UPDATE**
After NEngelhard answer, here the solution. I modified the first function as follows and it works!

```
def joyread(data):

foo = Float32MultiArray()
foo.data.append(255*data.axes[1])
foo.data.append(255*data.buttons[14])
pub.publish(foo)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/247993/alternative-publisher-for-joy_node/) by [marcoresk](https://answers.ros.org/users/28398/marcoresk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 76 on 2016-11-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

def joyread(data):
foo[0] = 4*data.axes[1]

You are missing the declaration. foo should be a Float32MultiArray, but then you'd rather have to write in foo.data.

Something closer to this should work: (I'm not quite sure how the foo.layout has to be initialized)

```
def joyread(data): 
  foo = Float32MultiArray()
  foo.data.append(4*data.axes[1])
  (...)
```

---

Originally posted by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) with karma: 3519 on 2016-11-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [marcoresk](https://answers.ros.org/users/28398/marcoresk/) on 2016-11-13**:
It works! It was the missing line you wrote. Thank you so much! You save my day.